# Updating a stored JSON in Mysql Database

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update a Stored JSON in my database and i am unable to run the following update query. I have copied below a select statement and an update statement

```
SELECT 
`core_animal_event`. `animal_id` AS `MilkingEvent_animalID`, 
JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(`core_animal_event`.`additional_attributes`, '$."62"')) AS `MilkingEvent_milkCompositeLitres`, 
coalesce(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(`core_animal_event`.`additional_attributes`, '$."68"')) + 
JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(`core_animal_event`.`additional_attributes`, '$."61"')) +
JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(`core_animal_event`.`additional_attributes`, '$."59"')))
FROM `core_animal_event` WHERE (`core_animal_event`. `event_type` = 2) AND (`core_animal_event`. `country_id` = '10');

UPDATE `core_animal`
SET
JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(`core_animal_event`.`additional_attributes`, '$."62"'))  = 
coalesce(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(`core_animal_event`.`additional_attributes`, '$."68"')) + 
JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(`core_animal_event`.`additional_attributes`, '$."61"')) +
JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(`core_animal_event`.`additional_attributes`, '$."59"')))
 WHERE (`core_animal_event`. `event_type` = 2) AND (`core_animal_event`. `country_id` = '10')
```

The following is the sample data from which we have a stored JSON column called additional_attribute and animal_id which is unique

```
# animal_id, additional_attributes
'2576', '{\"59\": null, \"61\": null, \"62\": null, \"63\": null, \"64\": null, \"65\": null, \"66\": null, \"67\": null, \"68\": null, \"69\": \"1\", \"70\": \"2\", \"71\": \"1\", \"72\": null, \"73\": \"2\", \"74\": \"1\", \"75\": null, \"76\": null, \"77\": [\"1\"], \"78\": \"32\", \"79\": \"70\", \"80\": \"4\", \"81\": null, \"82\": null, \"83\": null, \"84\": \"Mkiwa\", \"85\": \"19280\", \"86\": \"2405\", \"87\": \"TNZ000192802405\", \"88\": \"Brownwhite\", \"89\": \"1565789020239.jpg\", \"90\": \"1565789049469.jpg\", \"96\": null, \"97\": null, \"98\": null, \"99\": \"1\", \"100\": null, \"101\": null, \"102\": null, \"103\": null, \"104\": null, \"105\": null, \"106\": null, \"107\": null, \"108\": null, \"109\": null, \"110\": null, \"111\": null, \"112\": null, \"113\": null, \"114\": null, \"115\": null, \"116\": null, \"117\": null, \"118\": null, \"119\": null, \"120\": null, \"121\": null, \"122\": null, \"123\": null, \"124\": null, \"125\": null, \"126\": null, \"127\": null, \"128\": null, \"129\": null, \"130\": null, \"131\": null, \"132\": null, \"133\": null, \"134\": null, \"135\": null, \"136\": null, \"137\": null, \"138\": null, \"139\": null, \"141\": null, \"142\": null, \"143\": null, \"144\": null, \"145\": null}'
```

The following is an example of a create statement

```
CREATE TABLE `core_animal_event` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `animal_id` int NOT NULL,
  `event_type` int NOT NULL,
  `additional_attributes` json DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `org_id` (`country_id`),
  KEY `animal_id` (`animal_id`),
  KEY `event_type` (`event_type`),
  CONSTRAINT `core_animal_event_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`animal_id`) REFERENCES `core_animal` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=941817 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

Comment: Provide CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO script with sample data (3-4 records enough) and desired result for this data.

Comment: @Akina I have made the create statement insert statement is not included though

Comment: If you give an example of the source data and desired result for it, then anyone who wants to help you can check that the proposed solution gives the correct result.

Comment: PS. `COALESCE(val1 + val2 + val3)` is wrong. Anycase `val1 + val2 + val3` will be returned, even if it is NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape characters are not necessary here. I even think they may be the source of the problem.

Here's my code for the tests :

```
CREATE TABLE `core_animal_event` (
  `animal_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `additional_attributes` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`animal_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

INSERT INTO core_animal_event
(animal_id, additional_attributes, event_type, country_id)
VALUES(1, '{ "59": null, "61": null, "62": null, "63": null, "64": null, "65": null, "66": null, "67": null, "68": null, "69": "1", "70": "2", "71": "1", "72": null, "73": "2", "74": "1", "75": null, "76": null, "77": ["1"], "78": "32", "79": "70", "80": "4", "81": null, "82": null, "83": null, "84": "Mkiwa", "85": "19280", "86": "2405", "87": "TNZ000192802405", "88": "Brownwhite", "89": "1565789020239.jpg", "90": "1565789049469.jpg", "96": null, "97": null, "98": null, "99": "1", "100": null, "101": null, "102": null, "103": null, "104": null, "105": null, "106": null, "107": null, "108": null, "109": null, "110": null, "111": null, "112": null, "113": null, "114": null, "115": null, "116": null, "117": null, "118": null, "119": null, "120": null, "121": null, "122": null, "123": null, "124": null, "125": null, "126": null, "127": null, "128": null, "129": null, "130": null, "131": null, "132": null, "133": null, "134": null, "135": null, "136": null, "137": null, "138": null, "139": null, "141": null, "142": null, "143": null, "144": null, "145": null}', 2, 10);
```

Without escape characters `\`, your SELECT query work.

For your update, here's an example :

```
UPDATE core_animal_event
SET additional_attributes = json_set(additional_attributes, '$."62"',
        COALESCE(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(additional_attributes, '$."68"')) + 
            JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(additional_attributes, '$."61"')) +
            JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(additional_attributes, '$."59"')))
        )
WHERE (event_type = 2) AND (country_id = '10');
```

//-------

**EDIT**:
Be careful when using JSON_EXTRACT and COALESCE function, in case all values are null, the returned value is 0, not a null value.

**EDIT 2**:
Akina is right, your COALESCE function is no good... As you do, it's an addition (but maybe that's what you want...)

**EDIT 3**:
If you want to use COALESCE here's an example:

```
SELECT animal_id AS colID, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(additional_attributes, '$."62"')) AS col62, 
COALESCE (
    IF(JSON_TYPE(JSON_EXTRACT(additional_attributes, '$."68"'))='NULL', null, JSON_EXTRACT(additional_attributes, '$."68"')),
    IF(JSON_TYPE(JSON_EXTRACT(additional_attributes, '$."59"'))='NULL', null, JSON_EXTRACT(additional_attributes, '$."59"')),
    IF(JSON_TYPE(JSON_EXTRACT(additional_attributes, '$."61"'))='NULL', null, JSON_EXTRACT(additional_attributes, '$."61"'))
) AS result_of_coalesce
FROM core_animal_event WHERE (event_type = 2) AND (country_id = '10');
```